# Order by column in another table PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have tables like this

COUNT tbl
    id,  userid,  linkid,  count

```
                         4
                         1
                         6
```

LINKS tbl

```
id,  linkname,  linkurl
```

What i want to do is to order the 'linkname' column in order of the count column and put it in an array. I am struggling becasue i am not understanding how to use JOIN.

I need to get linkid WHERE userid = $userid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$userid = intval( $userid ); // Hopefully it's already an integer, 
                             // but protect yourself from SQL Injection

SELECT linkname, C.count FROM Links INNER JOIN `Count` C ON C.linkid = Links.id
WHERE userid = $userid
ORDER BY C.count ASC
```

Comment: almost worked, it displays the linkid, but i want to display the linkname WHERE userid = $userid

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `SELECT * FROM Links L JOIN Count C ON L.id = C.linkid` then you should have a count column.

Also, I recommend you don't use "count" as the name of a table since it is a SQL reserved word.

Comment: Contrariwise, I recommend that rather than trying to dodge around the ever-expanding list of MySQL reserved words, you just get into the habit of identifier-quoting all database, table and column names with backticks.  (I'd write an example but backticks are unescapable-as-far-as-I-know metacharacters to SO.)